# DataTables.net select inputs filter ignore time in datetime

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I'm using DataTables.net for rendering data in my laravel project. Now I came across with issue. 
In few columns I have data in dd.mm.yyyy H:i . I'm also using [DataTables.net select inputs filter](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

My column sorting does as it should (clicking on table headers). The problem is that select inputs are filled with ex:

```
31.12.2014 08:12
```

Now what I want is that filter will sort those columns as date (not date time). Because if my table has 100 rows, that means 100 select options under fields with datetime values. I want them to be grouped by date ignoring time.

Any solutions?

Comment: Are these dates being pulled from a database?

Comment: Yes, they are in 2014-06-26 09:37:14 format. Then I convert them to my locale using laravel.

Answer (score 0):

There would be a few solutions you could try.

I don't know how you have your query setup but you could possibly add a select on there and account for the difference right in your query and return just the date portion of it.

```
...->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT DATE(DATE_ADD(your_date_column, INTERVAL x HOUR)) AS your_date_column'))
```

Where `your_date_column` is the name of the column of the dates you are looking for and `x` is the number of hours to change, which can be a negative value if you are behind.  This will return a collection of unique dates which appear in your database which are offset by the number of hours.

The other solution would be to loop through your result set and set them to the dates as you go.  Carbon would make this fairly easy.

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $date = \Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($result->your_date_column);
    $date->addHours($hoursToAdd);
    $result->your_date_column = $date->toDateString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of select allows you select just a fixed portion of a field, than you can group by the portion you selected. So if you just need the first 10 characters from the date field you could select it like this.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('date',1,10) AS trimmed_date 
FROM table
GROUP BY trimmed_date;
```

This will return the information as trimmed_date. If you still wanted it to be date you could do it this way.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('date',1,10)
FROM table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING('date',1,10);
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer more?

Comment: This wont work, because datatables.net jquery plugin don't work like that. 
I select everything from my DB, then all this data is shown in an html table, then Jquery takes care of filtering that html table. 
Here is working example 
[link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) 

I know how to group in SQL, but I don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Pull your date/time data from the database as a unix timestamp, should look something like 13249141986.  When you create your dataTable, use a renderer for that column.  Here is a hint:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "data": dataSet, // in my case I'm building using data from a variable
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Name" },
        { "title": "Modified",
          "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
              return type === 'display' ? jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('M dd, yy', new Date(1000 * data)) : data;
            }
         }
    ]
} );
```

When the renderer is called for displaying, I'm parsing it to something readable, otherwise I'm just returning the raw seconds.  This should get you started.